# Xtics not working as expected with logscale in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

According to Gnuplot's documentation, `set logscale; set xtics 1,10,1000` should enable `logscale` and label the major tics on the x-axis starting from 1, ending at 1000, with each major tic in between being 10 times larger than the previous one. The increment factor is said to be multiplicative when in logscale. For some reason, this factor is being interpreted as additive on my computer, despite having set logscale.

```
set logscale
set xtics 1,10,100
plot 1/x
```

produces (gnuplot 5.2)

[image]

It's clear that the major tics are being labeled as if `10` is interpreted as an additive factor. In the end, I wish to have the standard log_base_10 scale tic marks (that is, ten tic marks between each major ones) but label the major tic marks with my own numbers.

**Update**

I am reading elsewhere that this might be a bug with the new gnuplot 5.2. To know for sure, would someone else confirm this? Perhaps if it's not too much of a hassle someone could try this out on their older gnuplot?

Comment: With version 5.0.6 it works like expected, but the logscale handling was reworked for 5.2. So probably that's a bug. You can report it here: https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/

Comment: Thank you; would you say gnuplot 5.0.6 is stable enough for me to downgrade to?

Comment: Stable of course, 5.0.6 is the 6th patchlevel for 5.0 (there is also 5.0.7). But 5.2 is newer ;)

Comment: Yes, I get excited about new updated software, but there are always bugs!

Comment: I reported the bug: https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1974/

Comment: I also posted here: https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1971. Someone seems to have had this issue earlier. The second reply is from a person working on the gnuplot team and he says it is fixed but its not!